Let A and B be events in the sample space, where $P(A) = 0$. Which of the following must be TRUE?

Let A and B be events in the sample space, where $P(A) = 0$. Which of
the following must be TRUE?
(a) A and B are independent.
(b) A and B are mutually exclusive.
(c) A must be a subset of B.
(d) None of the given options.

I was asked this question in one of my worksheets and the question stated to only choose one answer. Here is my analysis:
Since we know that $P(A) = 0$, then $P(A∩B) = 0$.
Thus, (b) is right and since for A and B to be both independent, $P(A∩B) = P(A)P(B) = 0$. And (a) is also right.
For option (c), since $P(A) = 0$, we implicitly know that A will be a subset of B since an empty set is a subset of any set. Thus (c) is also right?
In summary, I think that all (a), (b) and (c) are right options so should the answer be (d) in this case? Or could there be something wrong with this question?
Thanks for the help!!

$P(A)=0$ does not imply $A=\emptyset$

This may be of some help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/543390/if-the-probability-of-a-0-it-doesnt-mean-a-is-an-empty-set#:~:text=Furthermore%2C%20A%20cannot%20contain%20elements,A%20is%20an%20empty%20set.

What is your background? What do you know by $\mathrm P(A)$?

Let a loaded dice be such that the only possible outcome is 6. Let $A=\{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{2, 3, 6\}$, then

$P(A) = 0$
$A\cap B = \{2\}\not = \emptyset$ hence $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive
$A$ is not a subset of $B$

The only true sentence is (a) because if $P(A)=0$ then $0\le P(A\cap B)\le P(A) = 0 = P(A)P(B)$.

Logically it seems that all the 3 options a), b), and c) are not correct, so we are left with only 4th option i.e d). The reason is that the only info P(A)=0 is not sufficient to make any conclusion because if A and B is independent then P(A,B)=P(A)P(B) but vice-verse is not true

I thought $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ was the definition of pairwise independence

In the probability and statistic subject it is said that if A and B are independent then P(A,B) = P(A)P(B) but it is not said that if P(A,B)=P(A)P(B) then A and B are independent. Many times people misinterpret that vice-versa might also be true :)
Please do let me know if I have said anything wrong.

avenger: I think your statement  "it is not said that if $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent" is incorrect.  With three events $P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ would not necessarily imply independence but with only two I think $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ does imply independence.

Option c) is incorrect. Take the probability space ([0,1],B([0,1]),λ), λ:= Lebesgue measure and A={2/3}, B=[0,1/2]. λ(Α)=P(A)=0 but A is not a subset to B.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Thank you very much.

The emphasis on the question is that the option must be true, let us examine the options one by one.
Option (a)
$P(A) = 0$, thus $P(A \cap B)\; must = 0$, which is the criterion of independence, thus Option(a) is true
Option (b)
A and B need not necessarily be mutually exclusive. A can share part of  the unfavourable part of the sample space, thus Option (b) is not true
Option (c)
A certainly need not be a subset of B.It can occupy a part of the unfavourable sample space which B does not share, so option (c) is not true
Finally, we can see that only option (a) must be true
-
